# How to check which font the system uses?

Tags: linux, terminal, fonts

Is there a terminal command which allows me to see which font is used in a Linux terminal window?

Comment: That depends on what terminal you use and maybe on the distro, too. Could you please give us more information about that?

Comment: Sure: at the moment I am using the default terminal on Arch Linux. I thought that maybe there was a standard, distro-independent command for that

Comment: @user1301428 There is no such thing as "default terminal" on Arch Linux (unless you mean the Linux console).  Which desktop environment are you using?

Comment: If you're using a graphical terminal, you can surely find a menu entry called `Help -> About` where you can possibly find the name of your terminal application. Or do you mean the terminals that are accessable using STRG + ALT + 1-6?

Comment: @AluísioA.S.G. yes, sorry, I was tired :D I mean the Linux console. I am currently not using a desktop environment or a window manager.

Comment: @wullxz I mean the Linux console

Comment: If you're asking about the system, you should remove the https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/terminal tag.

Answer (score 2):

In GNOME I can print list of my gnome-terminal profiles with following command:

```
$ gconftool-2 --get /apps/gnome-terminal/global/profile_list
[Default,Profile0]
```

Then I can print font settings with:

```
$ gconftool-2 --get /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/font
Monospace 12
$ gconftool-2 --get /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Profile0/font
TakaoMincho Bold 36
```

Comment: Is there a DE-independent command?

Comment: he is asking about the Linux console, not about the GNOME terminal!

Comment: @user1301428 -- yes, of course! it works for the Gnome terminal only. Moreover, the original question was about the Linux console, which does not even need an X (or Wayland) system on the computer whatsoever

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about the Linux console, (or "teletype"), and not about  an X terminal emulator (see below for the X.org answer):

Unless you changed anything your Unix console is using the "default" font on your system. To learn what it is, type

```
setfont -v
```

For me, it gives

```
Loading 256-char 8x16 font from file /lib/kbd/consolefonts/default8x16.psfu.gz
Loading Unicode mapping table...
```

---

Now, if you are in the X11/ X.org terminal, check the contents of your

```
$ view /etc/default/console-setup
```

I get

```
FONTFACE="Fixed"
FONTSIZE="8x16"
```

-- that, is, the fixed-width 8x16 UTF-8 font

Comment: Just prints "Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console." on cpe:/o:opensuse:tumbleweed:20231022

Comment: @RokeJulianLockhart : this means that you are in X or on Wayland, and not in the console. If you are in X, use the second answer, with /etc/default/console-setup

Comment: Do you mean TTY rather than merely console? If so, that's worth specifying in the answer. I was using a console, but indeed through a display server. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @RokeJulianLockhart -- I meant /dev/tty* as opposite to the /dev/pts/*

Comment: @RokeJulianLockhart -- I have edited my answer a little bit, home it is less confusing by now, thank you